# Python: How to put unknow Multidimentional array in 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to know in python how to take a multidimensional array and put it in a 1D list. This thing work:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
sum(a,[])
```

I get this : [1,2,3,4]

But if I have a multidimensional with unknow dimension or not constant dimension like that :

```
a = [1,[3,4,[5,6,7]]]
```

How to get this : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/1907098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use recursion, something like this should work:

```
def flatten_list(l):
    new_l = []
    for item in l:
        if type(item) == type([]):
            new_l += flatten_list(item)
        else:
            new_l.append(item)
    return new_l
```

I did not test this code but the idea is there.

Comment: this one look like simple ! thanks ! And just because it's working as is without testing ! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
def flatten(lis):
    for i in lis:
        if isinstance(i, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(i, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(i):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield i
```

Taken from [Christian's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/1907098) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/1907098)

If you want to return a list, you can use this:

```
def flatten(lis):
    flat_list = []
    for i in lis:
        if isinstance(i, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(i, basestring):
            flat_list.extend(flatten(i))
        else:
            flat_list.append(i)
    return flat_list
```

However, for big lists, the generator function is much more efficient as it doesn't calculate the next value until it has too, unlike lists which stores its values in memory.

Comment: +1 for showing a generator. The input can be arbitrarily large and this will perform well.

Comment: In my software (Blender ... use python3) ... I got this error with this kind of solution : "global name "collection" is not difined"

Comment: ops ... it's a module I missed to import. But now the error is about "basestring".

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisGallant You must be using Python 3. Use `str` instead of `basestring`.